# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException using highlighter

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to get selected text from a JTextField. I found the .getHighlighter() function and it works. I get the desired text but it keeps throwing and index out of bounds exception. Can anybody tell me why?

PS: I've also tried checking if h != null and h[0] != null. Same result.

```
private void jTextField1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    Highlight[] h = jTextField1.getHighlighter().getHighlights();
    jLabel2.setText("Selected text: " + jTextField1.getText().substring(h[0].getStartOffset(), h[0].getEndOffset()));
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at interfacesprueba1.Ej3b.jTextField1MouseDragged(Ej3b.java:110)
at interfacesprueba1.Ej3b.access$000(Ej3b.java:14)
at interfacesprueba1.Ej3b$1.mouseDragged(Ej3b.java:42)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseDragged(AWTEventMulticaster.java:320)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6583)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please, post values of `jTextField1.getText()`, `h[0].getStartOffset()` and `h[0].getEndOffset()`

Comment: Have you checked that there are any highlights? `h.length > 0`

Comment: I've just tried h.length and it's not working. The values asked are qwerty, 2,3 (with the E in querty selected).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: I know what causes IndexOutOfBounds Exception. My problem is with getHighlighter() method.

Comment: You really should try to avoid one-liners like that sentence. It makes reading and debugging the code way more difficult.

Comment: But if you know then you can tell by your exception that, with an index of 0, you're going out of bounds on your array. What line of code is 110?

Comment: Fixed. Nevermind. It was length. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check array length also like this

```
private void jTextField1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        Highlight[] h = jTextField1.getHighlighter().getHighlights();
        if (h != null && h.length > 0) {
            jLabel2.setText(
                    "Selected text: " + jTextField1.getText().substring(h[0].getStartOffset(), h[0].getEndOffset()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html#getHighlights()) ever returns `null`.

Comment: ya we can directly check for length,i have just do null check for safer side :)

Comment: Same exception.

Comment: OK, I was testing something else. It did fix the problem.